# Tensor product - Addition of angular momenta

Tags: angular-momentum, tensor-calculus

In the book Quantum Mechanics - Cohen-Tannoudji, in chapter X, equation (B-5) says
$$
\vec{S^2} = (\vec{S_1} + \vec{S_2})^2 = \vec{S_1^2} + \vec{S_2^2} + 2\vec{S_1}\cdot\vec{S_2}
$$
and
$$
\vec{S_1}\cdot\vec{S_2} = S_{1x}S_{2x} + S_{1y}S_{2y} + S_{1z}S_{2z}.
$$

But in another notation, it would be

$$
\vec{S^2} = (\vec{S_1}\otimes 1 +1\otimes \vec{S_2})^2 = \vec{S_1^2}\otimes 1 + 1\otimes\vec{S_2^2} + 2\vec{S_1}\otimes\vec{S_2},
$$
where $1$ are de identity matrix of each Hilbert space.

So would $\vec{S_1}\otimes\vec{S_2} = \vec{S_1}\cdot\vec{S_2}$?

I could see that in another way:
$$
\vec{S_1}\cdot\vec{S_2} = (\vec{S_1}\otimes1)\cdot(1\otimes\vec{S_2}) = (\vec{S_1}\cdot 1)\otimes(1\cdot\vec{S_2}) = \vec{S_1}\otimes\vec{S_2}
$$

But 
$$
\vec{S_1}\otimes\vec{S_2} = S_{1x}\otimes S_{2x} + S_{1y}\otimes S_{2y} + S_{1z}\otimes S_{2z}.
$$
doesn't seem right to me. It would be the distribution of
$(S_{1x} + S_{1y} + S_{1z})\otimes (S_{2x} + S_{2y} + S_{2z})$.

Comment: At the end, do you mean the *trace* of $(S_{1x}+S_{1y}+S_{1z})\otimes (S_{2x}+S_{2y}+S_{2z})$?

Comment: No, I mean that $\vec{S_1}\otimes\vec{S_2}$ should equal $(S_{1x} + S_{1y} + S_{1z})\otimes (S_{2x} + S_{2y} + S_{2z}) = S{1x}\otimes S_{2x} + S_{1x}\otimes S_{2y} + ...$

Comment: Ah, ok. In terms of dot products, what you have written above would be $(\vec S_1\cdot [1,1,1])\otimes (\vec S_2 \cdot [1,1,1])$, as opposed to $\sum_{j}S_1^j\otimes S_2^j=\vec S_1 \cdot \vec S_2$.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't get why last term os $\vec{S^2}$ should be a dot product... isn't isn't $\vec{S_1} \cdot [1, 1, 1] =  S_{1x} + S_{1y} + S_{1z}$, as I wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $(\vec S_1\otimes 1) \cdot (1\otimes \vec S_2)$ is interpreted as a contraction over spatial indices. Hence, $\vec S_1\cdot \vec S_2=\sum_{ij} \delta_{ij}S_{1i} \otimes S_{2j}$.

By contrast, $(S_{1x}+S_{1y}+S_{1z})\otimes(S_{2x}+S_{2y}+S_{2z})=(\vec S_1\cdot [1,1,1])\otimes (\vec S_2\cdot [1,1,1])$.

Comment: I wrote the vectors in terms of 2-tensor components and got what you wrote. Thank you!